# Hibernate search is always returning an empty list

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-search

I am developping a java/jee application in which i am using spring boot and hibernate  as frameworks i used hibernate search for full text searching but unfortunately i always got an empty list as result.I am using hibernate version 5.1 and hibernate search orm  version 5.5.3.Final.Here is my code :

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple kinds of full-text queries.

The *keyword()* query will only match exactly the same keyword, so if you pass *matching("di*")* it will only find instances of the *Application* entity which have a literal field

```
 reference = "di*";
```

Which I'm guessing is not what you meant to do.

It looks like you want a wildcard query instead?

builder.keyword()**.wildcard()**.onField( "reference" ).matching( "di*" ).createQuery()

Have a look also at the new SimpleQuery DSL: *builder.simpleQueryString()*, another great way to create wildcard queries.

See also:

- [Wildcard queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#_wildcard_queries)
- [Simple Query String queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#_simple_query_string_queries)
- [Simple Query String announced](http://in.relation.to/2017/04/27/simple-query-string-what-about-it/)

Comment: thank you for your responce but i have also tried that and it is still not working